# Multiplication problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was solving the one physical numerical during which i came through a calculation
$$1255\times\left(\frac{170.474}1\right)\times\left(\frac{1000}1\right)\times\left(\frac{1}{48.26}\right)^3$$

Answer given by them is :$1.903\times10^3$

But when i calculated value of $(\frac{1}{48.26})^3$ in calculator it came $0.0000000000$.

So i thought that i am wrong because $0$ multiply by anything should be zero.

but then i multiplied the rest of value with $0.0000000000$ the calculator give me the answer$1.903\times10^3$!! Which was correct answer.

Why did calculator showed that answer??

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you didn't use a scientific calculator.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey i used advance calculator given in computer

Comment: Google gives $\dfrac{1}{48.26^3}=8.89688644e-6$. So the problem is with the precision used in your calculator.

Comment: In R it shows `[1] 8.896886e-06` which means your calculator stores it but not display it.

Comment: Windows calculator in scientific mode gives $8.8968864404041819438339235882368\times10^{-6}$. Your calculator stores this value in its memory and couldn't display the result.

Comment: i think that's the problem

Comment: I don't know what is the reason of such a result. I think you are using Ubuntu and I did the same computation with its calculator but I didn't get your result. The problem could be some configuration of the calculator, but I don't see how to solve it.

Comment: @ManuelFdzLpz i don't i think i should ask about configuration in ask Ubuntu

Comment: Did you really believe that $(1/48.26)^3=0\>$?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter i didn't relive that's why i asked this question :)

Comment: Plugging the whole expression on my calculator gives me $18958.597738$, which is not even close to the answer given by you. Did you type it right?

Comment: @JChau sorry i did mistake in typing the question it is 1255. Now you will get right answer:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calculator probably rounded the number at a specific point (that is what my calculator does). I do not like to use decimals, so I will use fractions.
$$1255\times 170.474\times 1000\times \left(\frac{1}{48.26}\right)^3$$
$$=1255\times 170.474\times 1000\times \frac{1}{48.26^3}$$
$$=1255\times 170.474\times 1000\times \frac{1}{112398.871976}$$
$$=213944870\times \frac{1}{112398.871976}$$
$$=\frac{213944870}{112398.871976}$$
Plugging this on my calculator gives me $1903.443213$, which is about $1.903\times 10^3$ (technically it is $1.903443213\times 10^3$, but the calculator probably rounded the decimal).

Even if the calculator gave an answer of $0.000000$, do you really believe that $\left(\frac{1}{48.26}\right)^3=0$? It does not make sense. Just use another calculator like Google's calculator, and you should get $8.89688644e-6$, which is $8.89688644\times 10^{-6}$